# Can't see "permissions" tab on android emulator. How to enable "permissions" tab?

Tags: android, permissions

I want to permit my App to send text messages. For this App must be given permission to do this. But I cant see "permission" tab on emulator. What should I do?

Comment: why cant u handle permission runtime? what is the android version of emulator?

Comment: its android version 5.1.1. If I try to handle it on runtime program crash asking for permission.

Comment: Put permission in manifest and runtime permission is from 6.0 and above, there is not   any permission settings on below 6.0

Comment: Thanks Pavan that's exactly I was looking for. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below android 6.0, google did not provide any option for users to manually turn permissions on and off. What you have to do is to set up a new emulator and install android 6.0 in it.